# Find the volume below $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}=1$ in the first quadrant

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I understand that we have to use transformation
$$x = u^2, y = v^2, z = w^2$$
but I cannot figure out the limits.

I just need a rough sketch of how to approach this. Could anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

We can still do it directly. For the set up, it should be:

$V = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{(1-\sqrt{x})^2} \int_{0}^{(1-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2} 1 dzdydx$

Comment: nice formula! $V=\frac{1}{90}$

Answer (score 2):

The region in $xyz$-space is the set of points which satisfy $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} \le 1$.

Under the given transformation, the inequality $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} \le 1$ becomes $u+v+w \le 1$.

Since we need our transformation to be 1:1, we need to restrict $u,v,w \ge 0$.

The region in the $uvw$-space is the set of points which satisfy $u,v,w \ge 0$ and $u+v+w \le 1$.

Can you find the bounds for this region? Also, don't forget the Jacobian when integrating.